# What is the EvalOp in Coq CompCert

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coq-extraction, compcert

The definition of EvalOp is in [`compcert.backend.SplitLongproof`](https://github.com/AbsInt/CompCert/blob/3837216731df1417eeb8885d472ffbd8f87fa144/backend/SplitLongproof.v#L154):

```
Ltac EvalOp :=
  eauto;
  match goal with
  | [ |- eval_exprlist _ _ _ _ _ Enil _ ] => constructor
  | [ |- eval_exprlist _ _ _ _ _ (_:::_) _ ] => econstructor; EvalOp
  | [ |- eval_expr _ _ _ _ _ (Eletvar _) _ ] => constructor; simpl; eauto
  | [ |- eval_expr _ _ _ _ _ (Elet _ _) _ ] => econstructor; EvalOp
  | [ |- eval_expr _ _ _ _ _ (lift _) _ ] => apply eval_lift; EvalOp
  | [ |- eval_expr _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ] => eapply eval_Eop; [EvalOp | simpl; eauto]
  | _ => idtac
  end.
```

What is strange about this definition is that `coqdoc --html` recognize `Eval` and `Op` as two separate tokens:

```
<span class="id" title="keyword">Eval</span><span class="id" title="var">Op</span>
```

Why would Coq allow two tokens with no separators (spaces) in the middle? Or is this a bug of `coqdoc`? Thanks for helping!

Comment: [Here](http://compcert.inria.fr/doc/html/SplitLongproof.html) I see `<span class="id">EvalOp</span>`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I compiled CompCert and the doc using coq 8.7.1+2 in opam. My doc command is `coqdoc --html -q  -R lib compcert.lib  -R common compcert.common  -R x86_64 compcert.x86_64  -R x86 compcert.x86  -R backend compcert.backend  -R cfrontend compcert.cfrontend  -R driver compcert.driver  -R flocq compcert.flocq  -R exportclight compcert.exportclight  -R cparser compcert.cparser --vernac-file lib/*.v common/*.v x86_64/*.v x86/*.v backend/*.v cfrontend/*.v driver/*.v flocq/*.v exportclight/*.v cparser/*.v` Do you know how the official doc is compiled, and why this bug happens on my machine?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Or could it be because there is a bug in compcert 3.2 while the bug was resolved in the compcert master version?

Comment: I don't know, but could it be an instance of [issue #2366](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/2366)?

Comment: Also, could it be that CompCert uses [coq2html](https://github.com/xavierleroy/coq2html) instead of coqdoc to generate HTML?

Comment: @AntonTrunov I see, so it is likely a bug in `coqdoc --html`. I would like to try the solution of issue #2366 (`cd theories && coqdoc -toc -html -d html *.v`), but how does it applies to the case where the v files are in multiple folders? For example, If I run `coqdoc` once for each folders in compcert, I guess I will lose the variable `href` links for the variables defined in different folders?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I either use generated coqdoc files or just browse/grep the source code.

Comment: `Eval` being a vernacular token, I think it's just some tool in the chain being confused about the proper tokenization. :-(

Comment: @Ptival Do you think the bug is in the Coq parser? Does `coqdoc` use the same parser as `coqc` does? If yes, is `coqc` safe in this case?

Comment: Last I checked, `coqdoc` and `coqc` used separate parsers.  In any case, `coqc` does not have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would Coq allow two tokens with no separators (spaces) in the middle? Or is this a bug of `coqdoc`?

This is a bug of `coqdoc`.  Coq does not allow two alphabetic tokens with no non-alphanumeric characters between them, but there are plenty of other examples of tokens without separators.  For example, this is valid Coq:

```
Definition(*no-spaces*)foo:=1.
```

This gets lexed as the tokens `Definition`, the comment `(*no-spaces*)`, `foo`, `:=`, `1`, and `.`, I believe.  You can also play silly games with numeric tokens, e.g.,

```
Coercion Nat.add:nat>->Funclass.
Axiom a:nat.
Check 1a:nat.
```

Because identifiers cannot start with numbers, Coq parses `1a` as `1` applied to `a`, which typechecks because of the `Coercion`.  You should probably not play games like this with Coq's parser.